# Corrupted Image Layer of DPR File (eCognition Project)

Tags: digital-image-processing, ecognition, corrupt, lidar-analyst

I just started working with eCognition a few months ago and it is my first time to encounter a problem.

I was on the refinement stage (and almost done manual brushing objects) when I found out that there was a display issue on my project. This has been observed after a power interruption had occurred.

As I asked my senior fellow, he mentioned that the file has been corrupted.

I just like to ask if anyone knows a way to fix it.

[image: Corrupted Segment]